# Batch adjustments for matplotlib charts

Tags: matplotlib

I have a batch of charts which need to be created using a standard template. The problem is that the number of digits in the Y-axis varies from set to set; this is causing a problem as I can't seem to get the layout to accomdate a ylabel + the digits without clipping.

Is there any suggestion of how to choose correct values for `subplot_adjust`, or make `tight_layout` keep the suptitle in mind?

Code currently looks approximately like this:

```
rc('text',usetex=True)
rc('font',family='serif')
mpl.rcParams.update({'font.size': 22})
fig = plt.figure(1,dpi=300,figsize=(4,4))
fig.suptitle(b.replace("_","-"))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
lx = 0
for i in instances:
    lx = max([lx,len(X[i])])
    plt.plot(X[i],Y[i])
plt.xlabel("X Label")
plt.ylabel("Y Label")
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.1, top=0.9) # Works for some charts, not others!
plt.savefig(b+".pdf",format="pdf")
```

Comment: Is all of the data in same range?  If so you can try fixing the y limits which would make the ticks (and hence the number of digits) the same on all of the graphs.

Comment: @tcaswell: Not even slightly; though, I'm thinking I can just force the digits. I'm also planning on gridding these plots eventually, so I'm also going to try creating a subplot grid in matplotlib directly. We'll see what works best.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out?

Comment: Yeah-- not happy at all with the solution (which was effectively your answer), but got it done.

Comment: It might be worth trying the newest version of `mpl`, a lot of work went into improving `tight_layout` and making at aware of all the artists in the figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
majorFormattor = matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%0.1f')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(majorFormattor)
```

[Docs](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter)